# php query row update

Tags: php, sql

i wanna update one row:

> do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET
>   solved=$solved WHERE id=$id");

and my second update:

> do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET
>   check=1 WHERE id=$id");

$id in these two are same. How join them together, so only one sql would be ?

Comment: Hopefully you're sanitizing `$id` properly, so little Bobby Tables won't be able to play with your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to seperate the fields being updated with **,** (comma)
Try this:

```
do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET solved=$solved, check=1 WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: @Neal: yes, but I think you were faster than me by 13 seconds :)

Comment: hehe to the victor goes the spoils ^_^

Answer (score 2):

commas.

```
do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET solved=$solved, check=1 WHERE id=$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET check = 1, solved = '".$solved."' WHERE id = ".$id.");
```

This should do the work.

Comment: why are you changing the sql statement with `'".`? there is no need for that

Answer (score 0):

```
do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET solved=$solved, check=1 WHERE id=$id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others above, this should work:

```
do_mysql_query("UPDATE helpcenter SET solved='$solved', check=1 WHERE id='$id'");
```

However, be sure to sanitize $id and $solved properly using mysql_real_escape_string() or something equivalent.